# Hover text in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

how to use hover text function on any link in jQuery ?
this is my code.

```
<a class="hover" href="#" >Google</a>
```

```js
$(".hover").mousemove(function () {
    var hovertext= $(this).attr('hovertext'); 
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean `title` attribute?

Comment: _"hover text function"_ ? What is that ?

Comment: when we move the pointer to some link it hover some text .

Comment: Do you want to set value of `hovertext` attribute in `title` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".hover").mousemove(function () {
    var hovertext= $(this).attr('hovertext'); 
    this.attr{title: hovertext};
});
```

The code I added is just the final line.  Javascript calls hovertext the "title" and you set it as an attribute of the node.

Comment: Title in quotations ?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I've added in a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```js
document.getElementById("hover").onmousemove = function() {myFunction(event)};

function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("hover").text = "hovered"
   
}
```

```html
<a id="hover" class="hover1" href="#" >Google</a>
```